# "Back to top" element which works with jQuery popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have a jQuery selectmenu list which opens as a popup because it so long. What I'd like is a "back to top" button at the end of the list. I found [this tutorial](http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/) which looks like it should do the trick, except that it doesn't show the "Back to Top" text because I imagine that it's underneath the popup. Any ideas how to get around this? Or another implementation of a "back to top" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Break it down by parts. The `<a href="#">Back to Top</a>` will automatically put you on the top of the page. It's no rocket science.

Then you can add some styling via CSS. In this case the tutorial uses the class "back to top". `<a href="#" class="back-to-top">Back to Top</a>`. You can make this look like whatever you want, no big deal.

However, I'll recommend you keep this bit of code, since is the one that positions it. `position: fixed; bottom: 2em; right: 0px;`. As a side note, replace `position:fixed` with `position:relative`, so it appears on the popup.

Then, you can add some nice smooth scrolling effects or whatever you want.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
});
```

Tell me how it goes. Cheers, Sebastian.